# how to draw a diagram in xgraph for my dropped file

Tags: ns2

I want to draw a diagram for my dropped file in ns2 (I'm a quite beginner). I've searched about it but the results made me so confused and couldn't try any of them because I don't know which code and which file do I need exactly.I have "tcl" file, "out.nam", "out.tr" and "dropped" files now, and what I want to know is: if I need any other file or not? and what should I code in terminal to have a diagram in xgraph?
sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

First : Please have a look into ns-allinone-2.3x/xgraph-12.*/examples/, to know the formatting of Xgraph plot files. And please run the examples.

Secondly, please read http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html (About example4.tcl).

The mentioned 'example4.tcl' is also included in xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_10.2015.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSW1YTjFLLVpOWTg/view?usp=sharing

Please run the ~30 default {Xgraph examples.tcl}. And watch plenty of xgraph plot files being created. And ... you can also read the files.tcl, to see how it is done.

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)[xgraph](/questions/tagged/xgraph)

Comment: It was so useful. I added the "tr" extension to my dropped file and add the "exec xgraph dropped.tr -geometry 800x400" to my "finish" procedure. now it works. Thank you.

Comment: No "extension" required. But xgraph plot files can of course have an ID, a suffix : Any suffix will do : .xgr, .tr, .data .  Doesn't matter.